# Why didn't Vader do anything since he knew that he was becoming redundant?

Tags: star-wars, darth-vader

Inspired by this [question.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/7280/70135) [This answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/7284/70135) pointed that Vader expected that he would be betrayed by Palpatine. **Since Vader knew that he was becoming redundant, why didn't he do anything about it?**

Comment: Don't get too choked up about the rule of two, if a pair gets split by a third, a fourth could be found too.  How else could they expand ranks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### Spoilers for Marvel's *Star Wars: Darth Vader* below.

In the canon comic series *Darth Vader*, we see Vader take on and kill various rivals for his apprenticeship.

[Tulon Voidgazer](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Tulon_Voidgazer):

[image]

[Aiolin Astarte](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Aiolin_Astarte):

[image]

[Morit Astarte](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Morit_Astarte):

[image]

[Karbin](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Karbin):

[image]

As Forrest Venable discusses in his answer, he also went to considerable lengths to convince Luke to join him against Palpatine.

> **Vader:** There is no escape! Don't make me destroy you. Luke, you do not yet realize your importance. You've only begun to discover your power! Join me, and I will complete your training! With our combined strength, we can end this destructive conflict, and bring order to the galaxy.

Comment: What about Cylo himself?

Comment: @Adamant He was the main scientist of the replacement apprentice initiative, but I don't think he himself was considered a rival.

Comment: Yes, but surely killing him was also “doing something.”

Answer (score 49):

Vader spent a fair amount of effort trying to turn Luke to his side. If he succeeded Luke would have sided with Vader when Darth Sidious makes them fight over who will be his apprentice. Together, they would murder the Emperor and take his place, "ruling the galaxy as father and son".

That seems like a reasonable plan. Both Vader and Luke are capable warriors and this would be a time when they would both be present and Sidious would be relatively unlikely to have additional guards because this was private Sith business. Had Luke accepted the initial offer, Vader would also have had plenty of time to train him to become a better duelist which would have increased their odds of success.

Comment: In addition to this I would point out Anakin's hubris in Episode II where he expresses to Padme his clear desire and belief that he alone could make better decisions and lead the Republic/Empire by forcing everyone to acquiesce to his ideas about how they all should live. The premise of the question is that Vader was working for Palpatine to survive or because he had to, and not because he chose to or because he liked Palaptines ideas, in order to get one step closer to his ideas for a perfect galaxy and how he would bring them about.